# Вставить картинку в ДИВ из списка. JS

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a href="#modal" class="rectangle_small"></a>

    <div id="modal" class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog">
        <img src="img/printer-with-written-paper.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/printer-with-written-paper.svg" alt="">
        <img src="img/printer-with-written-paper.svg" alt="">
    </div>
```

есть много ссылок(квадратики) на модальное окно с картинками. В модальном окне выбирается картинка. Нужно реализовать: из какой ссылки(квадратика) было вызвано модальное окно, туда и нужно поместить выбранную картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не ясно что есть, а что реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь я тебя правильно понял...

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
var index = null;
for (let i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#modal').classList.add('modal');
    index = i;
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    block[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img[i].src + ')';
    document.querySelector('#modal').classList.remove('modal');
    index = null;
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #454544;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

#modal {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.9);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .1s;
}

#modal.modal {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  transition: opacity 0.1s, width 0.3s, heigth 0.3s 0.3s, background 0.1s;
}

img {
  width: 330px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: background 0.5s 0.1s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1016500/02e248bb-ced8-489a-ad98-30a6259ce7fe/s1200);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="modal" class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog">
    <img src="https://carsmind.com/cache/image/a902ea3442f4043e1a0c7eb3f5e2a52d/acc_p_c295c_Lamborghini_Huracan_LP_610-4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://carsmind.com/cache/image/224b9c4dcad8a12a692414d9d7f075cf/acc_p_8e82c_lamborghiniaventadorj.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://carsmind.com/cache/image/a60ecb7a48619cea7d0f2720982db04f/acc_p_17b30_ferrari-812-superfast-800ps.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: дело в том что 
<a href="#modal" class="popup rectangle_small"></a> и <div id="modWindow"></div>
это по сути один объект должен быть. и из какого объекта вызвано модальное окно туда и вставить нужно картинку

Comment: Как два объекта могут быть, одним и тем же объектом.... Объясни толком, что ты хочешь реализовать... Только не в комментарии, а правь вопрос нормально и объясни суть проблемы...

Comment: Надеюсь, щас понятнее изложил, что требуется

Comment: Ок понял... минутку

Comment: Я тебя правильно понял?

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. То, что нужно

Comment: Вижу правильно понял... Рад был помочь))